# How do you combine two tabs into one floating window in Intellij?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

In Eclipse I can just drag-and-drop two tabs into one window.  For instance, I like to keep my JUnit and Search tabs together:

[image]

How can you do this in Intellij?

Comment: eclipse wins again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open projects as tabs in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397429/how-to-open-projects-as-tabs-in-intellij)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't combine multiple floating panels into one in IntelliJ IDEA. Feel free to [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

Comment: Too bad, do you know there are any plans for this in v11?

Comment: I didn't find similar request, so it's unlikely.

Comment: I guess I can use the tabs on the main window instead, it is just much less intuitive.  I submitted a feature request as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no such feature in IntelliJ (at least as of version 11). In my opinion, IntelliJ has much less support to dual monitor than Eclipse. There is an existing feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77163 , please help to vote it up.

Comment: FYI I created that request, was assigned to someone a few months ago.

Comment: July 2020, still not possible, it seems.