# How do you merge all your open windows in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I noticed this was asked in a similar question a couple years ago: [How do you combine two tabs into one floating window in Intellij?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173170/how-do-you-combine-two-tabs-into-one-floating-window-in-intellij)

But I don't see anywhere that this has been implemented in a current version of IntelliJ (I have a very recent version - 14.0.1)

Is this still a feature that doesn't exist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open projects as tabs in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397429/how-to-open-projects-as-tabs-in-intellij)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA version 14.1, combining multiple floating toolwindows into one toolwindow with multiple tabs is still a feature that does not exist.

Floating editor windows can be combined into a single window by drag&drop.

Comment: Is there a way this can be implemented as a feature? Would be super useful :)

Comment: Floating windows cannot be combined - that statement is entirely false.

Comment: @specializt Floating *editor* windows can be combined. If you don't know what a floating editor window is or how to combine them, it's not a good reason to remove valid information from an answer. The issue you've linked to in your edit refers to toolwindow tabs, not editor windows.

Answer (score 30):

In IDEA 2022.2 was added new function

On macOS, you can merge all opened project windows into one, turning them into tabs.

Make sure that there are several IntelliJ IDEA projects opened in separate windows.

1. From the main menu, select Window | Merge All Project Windows.
2. Drag a project's tab to work with the project in a separate window
   again.

[link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/open-close-and-move-projects.html#merge-project-windows)

Comment: I have just updated to 2022.3 and the function seems to be gone again?

Comment: Actually I just found out it only stopped working if you have enabled New UI in Appearance & Behavior. If this option is disabled merge all project windows is still present.

Comment: @Reader in 2023.1 this option is available again

Comment: Can I configure IDEA such that new projects are opened in the merged state by default?

Answer (score 15):

i dont have a `merge` option in the `window` menu like in other apps, but there's a workaround: open a project -> fullscreen -> open another project -> choose open in new window (while intellij is in fullscreen) -> voila! tabs

Comment: so THAT's the rule, when it opens in new tab or new window. fullscreen. been wondering about that.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution to this would be to go to:
**`Window -> Merge All Project Windows`**

Answer (score 4):

If you make your current window fullscreen and then open another folder it would stay combined.

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same problem (on macOS) with *drag & drop*.

I found this old post, also this [JetBrains KB article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Managing_Editor_Tabs.html#splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window) about IntelliJ in general, going through its features.

Seeing the animated GIF under **Editor Tabs -> Split Editor Window**
It forced me into experimenting.

I found out on macOS, that you need to be holding (while dragging) a modifier key, in my case *Option ⌥* key.
And then the *drag & drop* feature for Editor's TAB in any windows started to work like a magic.

Comment: This was a perfect solution